# What is the correct operation for returning an iterable of server roles?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I am attempting to iterate over the output of `discord.Server.roles` in order to output each role on the server I am connecting to.

The documentation states this for the declaration:

> roles
>
> A list of `Role` that the server has available.

However it seems that the resulting output is a `class` called `member_descriptor` which is non iterable.

See my example below:

```
import discord
import asyncio

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(type(discord.Server.roles))
    try:
        for i in discord.Server.roles:
            print(i)
    except:
        print("Object is not iterable")

client.run(MY_SESSION_KEY)
```

Is anyone aware of whether it is possible to return a list of roles that a server has as this declaration is not returning a list but a class?

Comment: You haven’t told your program with server to display the roles from, `discord.Server` is just a descriptor class, you need to use an actual server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a realised server object, not just the class definition.

Basically, instead of using `discord.Server`, you should be using `client.get_server("ID of server")`

```
def on_ready():
    server = client.get_server("id")
    for r in server.roles:
        print(r.name)
```